# Mass hanging by a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, harmonic-oscillator, coordinate-systems, spring

I have a mass hanging from the ceiling by a spring, with costant $k$, and wih gravity $g$. Using analytical mechanics I got to the differential equation:

$$
\ddot{x} + \frac{k}{m}x + g = 0
$$

The solution of this equation (at least the one I got) is

$$
x(t) = -\frac{gm}{k} + A \cos{wt} + B \sin{wt}
$$

with $w = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$

But this doesn't make sense if, for example, initially my mass is at $x=0$. How can I get a different solution (if there is another one)?

Comment: If the mass is initially in the position of equilibrium, it doesn't oscillate. The initial conditions determine $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oops, that's true sorry for that mistake, anyway, my question was not about that. And by determining the constants you don't get the solution I'm looking for anyway.

Comment: What solution are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> But this doesn't make sense if, for example, initially my mass is at
>   $x=0$.

$$x(0) = -\frac{gm}{k} + A\cos(0) + B\sin(0) = 0 \Rightarrow A = \frac{gm}{k} $$

Thus,

$$x(t) = -\frac{gm}{k}\left(1 - \cos(\omega_0t) \right) + B\sin(\omega_0t)$$

That is, you must still specify the initial *velocity* to find a unique solution.

$$v(0) = \dot x(0) = -\omega_0A\sin(0) + \omega_0B\cos(0) \Rightarrow B = \frac{v(0)}{\omega_0}$$

and so, finally

$$x(t) = -\frac{gm}{k}\left(1 - \cos(\omega_0t) \right) + \frac{v(0)}{\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0t)$$

What, about this, doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

The constants $A$ and $B$ are determined according to the initial conditions of $x$ and $\dot{x}$. However, the mass will always oscillate around the point 
$ x = -\frac{gm}{k} $ whatever your initial conditions are. When you give the initial conditions, $x(t_{0})$ and 
$ \dot{x}(t_{0}) $, you must solve the following linear system for A and B.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x(t_{0}) = -\frac{gm}{k} + A\sin{(\omega t)} + B \cos{(\omega t)} \\ 
\dot{x}(t_{0}) = A\cos{(\omega t)} - B\sin{(\omega t)}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

For example, if $x(t_{0}) = 0$, as you sad, and $\dot{x}(t_{0}) = v$ (for simplicity, consider $t_{0} = 0$). Therefore, $A = -v$ and $B = \frac{gm}{k}$.

I feel like I haven't answered your question because I don't see what doesn't make sense for you in this sentence "But this doesn't make sense if, for example, initially my mass is at x=0. How can I get a different solution (if there is another one)?"